# How to filter JSON string

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

In my application method populate JSON string as follows by using method called `GetAllProvince()`, Please keep note `GetAllProvince()` is web method

```
public string GetAllProvince()
{
    NccEntity nccEnti = getLtsLobbyInstance();
    DataTable dt = nccEnti.GetAllBranchesAndRegions();
    JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    return jsSerializer.Serialize(dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(row => row["RegionId"], row => row, (key, values) => new ProvinceWithBranches
    {
        Value = key.ToString(),
        Province = values.Select(row => row["RegionName"].ToString()).FirstOrDefault(),
        Branches = values.Select(row => new BranchItem
        {
            Value = row["BranchId"].ToString(),
            Province = row["BranchName"].ToString(),
            IsValid = row["IsTestBranch"].ToString()
        })
    }));
}
```

The class called `ProvinceWithBranches`

```
public class ProvinceWithBranches
{
    public string Value;
    public string Province;
    public IEnumerable<BranchItem> Branches;
}
```

The class called `BranchItem`

```
public class BranchItem
{
    public string Value;
    public string Province;
    public string IsValid;
}
```

The above method generating JSON string as follows,

```
[
  {
    "Value": "21",
    "Province": "Default",
    "Branches": [
      {"Value": "1108", "Province": "davie", "IsValid": "False"},
      {"Value": "1107", "Province": "Ab area109", "IsValid": "False"},
      {"Value": "1105", "Province": "Hollywood", "IsValid":"False"},
      {"Value": "1105", "Province": "Ft. Lauderdale", "IsValid":"False"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Value": "17",
    "Province": "East",
    "Branches": [
      {"Value": "212", "Province": "area109", "IsValid": "False"},
      {"Value": "219", "Province": "lauderdale", "IsValid": "False"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Value": "24",
    "Province": "East11",
    "Branches": [
      {"Value": "211", "Province": "area108", "IsValid": "False"},
      {"Value": "218", "Province": "area109", "IsValid": "False"},
      {"Value": "1102", "Province": "area999", "IsValid": "False"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Value": "25",
    "Province": "N25",
    "Branches": [
      {"Value": "213", "Province": "davie", "IsValid": "False"},
      {"Value": "220", "Province": "area999", "IsValid": "False"},
      {"Value": "220", "Province": "areda999", "IsValid": "False"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Now my requirement is I need to pass the parameter to that method as `GetAllProvince(string searcKey)` and based on the `searcKey` only relevant data should be filtered and return,

**as example 1**,
when the `searcKey = Default` following result should be returned (all the match cases should return either root or branch level)

```
[
  {
    "Value": "21",
    "Province": "Default",
    "Branches": [
      {"Value": "1108", "Province": "davie", "IsValid": "False"},
      {"Value": "1107", "Province": "Ab area109", "IsValid": "False"},
      {"Value": "1105", "Province": "Hollywood", "IsValid":"False"},
      {"Value": "1105", "Province": "Ft. Lauderdale", "IsValid":"False"}
    ]
  }
]
```

**example 2**,
when the `searcKey = area109` following result should be returned (all the match cases should return either root or branch level)

```
[
  {
    "Value": "21",
    "Province": "Default",
    "Branches": [
      {"Value": "1107", "Province": "Ab area109", "IsValid": "False"},
    ]
  },
  {
    "Value": "17",
    "Province": "East",
    "Branches": [
      {"Value": "212", "Province": "area109", "IsValid": "False"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Value": "24",
    "Province": "East11",
    "Branches": [
      {"Value": "218", "Province": "area109", "IsValid": "False"}
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I do this, please help me I'm stacked on this 2days. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have control over the `nccEnti.GetAllBranchesAndRegions()` method? It seems to me that maybe it's running some kind of SQL? If so, that might be an ideal place to insert some filter criteria. So `nccEnti.GetAllBranchesAndRegions(string search)`, then in that method apply the appropriate filter criteria.

Comment: ya `GetAllBranchesAndRegions()`  method running Stored procedure.But I need to filter data through this method

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't filter the json string. I would deserialize the json string into a list of ProvinceWithBranches and then do a loop reading the IEnumerable BranchItem class into something,then you could do linq query on that. Or an inner loop if you like. I think you pretty much have what you need.

Or why are you not doing a search on the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize to array of    ProvinceWithBranches and then

```
    private  IEnumerable<ProvinceWithBranches> Get(IEnumerable<ProvinceWithBranches> source,string filter)
          {
             var firstConditionResults= source.Where(p => p.Province == filter);
              var secondConditionResults = source.Where(p => p.Province  !=filter).Select(p=>new ProvinceWithBranches{
Value = p.Value,
Province = p.Province,
Branches = p.Branches.Where(branch=>branch.Province==filter) } );

              return firstConditionResults.Concat(secondConditionResults);
          }
```

Comment: where should I apply this method

Comment: Please keep note `GetAllProvince()` is web method

Comment: As i understand you have to filter collection of ProvinceWithBranches, yes? source is this collection , so i change parameters for you to understand, ok?